# MongoDB query to find the list in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents are like this:

```
{
    "date" : 20200817,
    "items" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "item1", "values" : ["val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "item2", "values" : ["val1", "val4"]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "item3", "values" : ["val1", "val3"]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get list of `name` of `items` that `val3` is exist in `values` like this

`['item1', 'item3']`

I have this query :

```
db.test.find({
    'dateM': 20200817,
    'items': {
        '$elemMatch':{
            'values':{
                '$elemMatch':{
                    $in:['val3']
                }
            }
         }
     }
}, {'lists.name': 1})
```

but i get list of name of all items.

Where is my query wrong?

What can I do?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use aggregation there. This is one way you can achieve

```
[
  {
    $project: {
      output: {
        $map: {
          input: {
            $filter: {
              input: "$items",
              cond: {
                $in: [
                  "val3",
                  "$$this.values"
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          in: "$$this.name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sZuiylhccLj)

Answer (score 0):

The query you have should return only documents that contain at least one item with `val3`.

If returning only the first matching element is sufficient, you use the projection form of [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/index.html#elemmatch-projection), otherwise, you will need to either use aggregation or filter the array on the client side.